# How to adjust width of the image on the slick-track

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I have a problem about the width of slick.js Where the box on the slick-track exceeds the page on the website.

Please pay attention to the image I uploaded this:

[image: Slick Js Issue]

for the use of my program code more or less like this:

```js
jQuery('.image-slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1.7,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  arrows: false,
  dots: false,

});
```

```css
.image-slider .slick-slide {
  margin: 0 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image-slider a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-slider img {
  width: 860px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class='image-slider'>
  <div class='overlay-container'>
    <a href='#'><img src='http://www.sixteenconsulting.com/sixteenblog/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/veille_complexe-800x533.jpg' />
      <div class='overlay'>
        <div class='text' />
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='overlay-container'>
    <a href='#><img src=' http://www.herbusiness.co.ke/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/battlefield_africa_winners-800x533.jpg '/>
      <div class='overlay '>
          <div class='text '/>
        </div>
     </a>
                                      </div>
     <div class='overlay-container '>
        <a href='# '><img src='https://disrupts.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/00948135202729.56ed9d795bc5b-2-800x533.jpg '/>
      <div class='overlay '>
          <div class='text '/>
        </div>
     </a>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It would be better if you create JSFiddle, CodePen or similar instead of pasting picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't work this out for ages myself. I was changing the

```
 <img width="200px" href="myimage.png">
```

in the div's but that didn't work. Also I'm using tables so its even more complicated. This can create lots of white space after the images.

Because the whole thing is responsive you need to use **width with a percentage** to make them work correctly, so that it scales as you change your screen width.

```
 <img width="100%" href="myimage.png">
```

or some percentage of the screen.